# Does the link function in a GLM influence the plot of residuals?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, residuals

Could an inappropriate link function contribute to non-uniform residuals in a GLM, or could that only be caused by an inappropriate error structure?

Comment: Hi there, could you elaborate further on what you mean by "non-uniform" residuals?

Comment: It's unusual for the choice of link function to matter much, when fitting GLMs - this is effectively what the Li-Duan theorem says.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A brief answer is yes an inappropriate link function can lead to residuals appearing "non-random".   however it can also be due to a predictor which needs to be transformed.  I am assuming that you are refering to a plot of residuals against the linear predictor.

One way to check that it isn't t a predictor is to create pseudo "partial residuals".  These are done by $u_{ij}=\hat{g}(y_{i})-x_{i}^T\hat{\beta}+x_{ij}\hat{\beta}_{j}$ where i indexes observations and j indexes variables.  The "hat" on the link function refers to the first order taylor series of g commonly refered to as the working response in a irls algorithm.  you plot $u_{ij}$ against $x_{ij}$ (ie one plot per covariate) and it should look like a straight line.  If this passes then i would consider changing the link function.  Of course this is only feasible when you only have a small number of variables.

Note that there are no hard and fast rules for using diagnostics - this is one approach of many.